# Cannot post slack webhook url in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I wanted to post slack webhook, but I get an error.

This works:

```lisp
(defun post-slack ()
  (drakma:http-request "https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx"
      :method :post
      :content-type "application/json"
      :parameters '(("payload" . "{\"username\":\"bot\",\"icon_emoji\":\":hatching_chick:\",\"text\":\"name: ~A \n email: ~A \n content: ~A \",\"as_user\":true}"))))
```

But this does not:

```lisp
(defun post-slack (name email text)
    (setq *payload* (format nil "{\"username\":\"bot\",\"icon_emoji\":\":hatching_chick:\",\"text\":\"<@U7RM4J8MR> name: ~A \n email: ~A \n text: ~A \",\"as_user\":true}" name email text))
    (drakma:http-request "https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx"
        :method :post
        :content-type "application/json"
        :parameters '(("payload" . *payload*))))
```

This is my error:

```
The value
  CAVEMAN-STUDY.CONTROLLER::*PAYLOAD*
is not of type
  LIST
when binding SB-C::FAST
   [Condition of type TYPE-ERROR]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry SLIME REPL evaluation request.
 1: [*ABORT] Return to SLIME's top level.
 2: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "new-repl-thread" RUNNING {1008826443}>)

Backtrace:
  0: (FIND-IF-NOT #<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (DRAKMA::THING) :IN DRAKMA:HTTP-REQUEST) {22D088AB}> ("payload" . CAVEMAN-STUDY.CONTROLLER::*PAYLOAD*) :KEY #<FUNCTION CDR>)
  1: (DRAKMA:HTTP-REQUEST #<PURI:URI https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxx> :METHOD :POST :CONTENT-TYPE "application/json" :PARAMETERS ("payload" . CAVEMAN-STUDY.CON..
  2: (SB-INT:SIMPLE-EVAL-IN-LEXENV (CAVEMAN-STUDY.CONTROLLER:POST-SLACK "aaa" "bbb" "ccc") #<NULL-LEXENV>)
  3: (EVAL (CAVEMAN-STUDY.CONTROLLER:POST-SLACK "aaa" "bbb" "ccase"))
 --more--
```

Please tell me how to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing `(("payload" . *payload*))` to `drakma:http-request`,
and `*payload*` here is *not* evaluated, i.e., it is passed as a `symbol`,
not its value.

What you probably want is something like

```
(defun post-slack (name email text)
  (let ((payload (format nil "..." ...)))
    (drakma:http-request "https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxx"
                         :method :post
                         :content-type "application/json"
                         :parameters `(("payload" . ,payload)))))
```

Note that I replaced [`setq`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_setq.htm) with [`let`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_let_l.htm).

PS. You can also use `(list (cons "payload" *payload*))` instead of `` `(("payload" . ,payload)) `` if you want to avoid [backquote](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/02_df.htm).

Comment: More simply `(list ("payload" . *payload*))` ?

Comment: @Ehvince: no, this will be an `type-error`. You need `(list (cons "payload" *payload*))`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking about Slack:

- https://github.com/dptd/cl-slack (seems the most up to date and documented)
- https://github.com/m0cchi/cl-slack
- https://github.com/kkazuo/slack-client (in Quicklisp)
- https://github.com/fiddlerwoaroof/slacker (most recent, no doc)
- https://github.com/stryku/jasa (2017)

There are also more Slack bots.

I discovered these with [quicksearch](https://github.com/tkych/quicksearch/) (I didn't know it was this handy).